# How to calculate Android Network Throughput

Tags: networking, throughput

I am calculating the network throughput

throughput=total packet(received)/total time consumed.

I have created a dedicated socket with the server and uploading and downloading the file. The output which i am getting is not upto the mark
code is as below:

```
public void uploadTest() throws Exception
{
      byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
      Utility.debugMessage(getName()+" uploadTest getLocalAddress() = "+ mUploadSocket.getLocalAddress()+" getLocalPort() = "+ mUploadSocket.getLocalPort()+" isBound() = "+mUploadSocket.isBound()+" isConnected() = "+ mUploadSocket.isConnected());
      DataOutputStream localDataOutputStream = new DataOutputStream(mUploadSocket.getOutputStream());
      sendMessage(Constants.MSG_CONN_LATENCY,(int)initiatingConnectionTime/* (System.currentTimeMillis()-initiatingConnectionTime)*/,-1,null);
      String uploadFilePath=null;

      uploadFilePath= Utility.createFileOnSdCard(testCaseDetails.getFileSize());

    int totalCycle=testCaseDetails.getCycle();
    double allCycleThroughPut=0;
      Utility.debugMessage(getName()+" uploadTest ToTal Available bytes","localDataInputStream.available() :: "+localDataOutputStream.size());
      for(int i=1;i<=totalCycle;i++)
      {
      long totalTime=0L;`enter code here`
      long updateDelta=0;
      long bytesRead=0L;
      long totalReceived=0L;
      File testFile = new File(uploadFilePath);
      fileSize=testFile.length();
      FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(testFile);
      BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(fis);
      while((bytesRead=bis.read(arrayOfByte))>Constants.NO_DATA)
      {
          long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
          localDataOutputStream.write(arrayOfByte,0,(int)bytesRead);
          totalReceived+=bytesRead;
          int progress=(int)((totalReceived/(double)fileSize)*100);
          Utility.debugMessage(NAME+" uploadTest Downloading  "," progress = "+progress+"totalSend = "+totalReceived);
          updateDelta =System.currentTimeMillis() - currentTime;

          if(sendYUpdate)
          {//Check y axis max value
                  sendMessage(Constants.MSG_UPDATE_Y_AXIS_LIMIT,(int)(Utility.calculate(updateDelta, bytesRead).getKilobits()),-1,  null);
              if(skipCounter==0)
              {
                  sendYUpdate=false;
              }
              else
              {
                  skipCounter--;
              }
          }
          else
          {

              sendMessage(Constants.MSG_UPDATE_STATUS,progress,(int) totalReceived, Utility.calculate(updateDelta, bytesRead));

          }
          totalTime+=updateDelta;
      }

      bis.close();
      long downloadTime=totalTime;

      SpeedInfo currentAverageThrougput=Utility.calculate(downloadTime, totalReceived);
      allCycleThroughPut+=currentAverageThrougput.getKilobits();
      sendMessage(Constants.MSG_CYCLE_STATUS, -1,i,currentAverageThrougput );
      sendYUpdate=true;
      }
      localDataOutputStream.close();

      sendMessage(Constants.MSG_COMPLETE_STATUS,(int)(allCycleThroughPut/totalCycle),-1,null);

        if(!Constants.RUN_ON_LOCAL)
            {

                    try {

                        Utility.closeSocket( con,Utility.getSharePrefValue(con, Constants.SERVER_BASE_URL)+"/TestMetrico/metrico/closeConnection",Integer.parseInt(Utility.getSharePrefValue(con, Constants.SOCKET_SERVER_PORT)));
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

        }
}


public void downloadTest() throws IOException
{
      int totalCycle=testCaseDetails.getCycle();
         double allCycleThroughPut=0;
     for(int i=1;i<=totalCycle;i++)
     {
      byte[] arrayOfByte = new byte[BUF_SIZE];
      if(mDownloadSocket.isClosed())
      {
          mDownloadSocket=null;
          mDownloadSocket=new Socket();
          connectDownload();
      }

      Utility.debugMessage(NAME+" downloadTest Start Downloading LocalAddress = "+ mDownloadSocket.getLocalAddress()+" getLocalPort = "+mDownloadSocket.getLocalPort()+" isBound = "+mDownloadSocket.isBound()+" isConnected = "+mDownloadSocket.isConnected());
      DataInputStream localDataInputStream = new DataInputStream(mDownloadSocket.getInputStream());
      sendMessage(Constants.MSG_CONN_LATENCY,(int) initiatingConnectionTime /*(System.currentTimeMillis()-initiatingConnectionTime)*/,Constants.PARAMETER_NOT_USED,null);

      Utility.debugMessage(NAME+" downloadTest ToTal Available bytes","localDataInputStream.available() :: "+localDataInputStream.available());



      float updateDelta=0;
      long received=0L;
      long totalTime=0L;
      long totalReceived=0L;
      long currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
      while (( received=localDataInputStream.read(arrayOfByte)) > Constants.NO_DATA)
      {
          totalReceived+=received;
          int progress=(int)((totalReceived/(double)1048576)*100);

          updateDelta = System.currentTimeMillis()-currentTime;

          Utility.debugMessage(NAME+" downloadTest Downloading buffer", "Received bytes= "+received+"totalReceived bytes= "+totalReceived+"updateDelta time = "+updateDelta);
          if(sendYUpdate)
          {//Check y axis max value
                  sendMessage(Constants.MSG_UPDATE_Y_AXIS_LIMIT,(int)( Utility.calculate(updateDelta, received).getKilobits()),-1,  null);
              if(skipCounter==0)
              {
                  sendYUpdate=false;
              }
              else
              {
                  skipCounter--;
              }
          }
          else
          {

              sendMessage(Constants.MSG_UPDATE_STATUS,progress,(int) totalReceived,  Utility.calculate(updateDelta, received));

          }

          totalTime+=updateDelta;
          currentTime=System.currentTimeMillis();
      } 


      long downloadTime=totalTime;//(totalTime-start);
      SpeedInfo currentAverageThrougput=Utility.calculate(downloadTime, totalReceived);
      allCycleThroughPut+=currentAverageThrougput.getKilobits();
      sendMessage(Constants.MSG_CYCLE_STATUS, -1,i,currentAverageThrougput );
      sendYUpdate=true;

      localDataInputStream.close();
      mDownloadSocket.close();
      }


      sendMessage(Constants.MSG_COMPLETE_STATUS,(int)(allCycleThroughPut/totalCycle),-1,null);

        if(!Constants.RUN_ON_LOCAL)
            {
                    try {

                        Utility.closeSocket( con,Utility.getSharePrefValue(con, Constants.SERVER_BASE_URL)+"/TestMetrico/metrico/closeConnection",Integer.parseInt(Utility.getSharePrefValue(con, Constants.SOCKET_SERVER_PORT)));
                    } catch (Exception e1) {
                        e1.printStackTrace();
                        }

        }

}


    public static SpeedInfo calculate(final float downloadTime,
            final float bytesIn) {

        SpeedInfo info = new SpeedInfo();
        float downloadTimeTemp = downloadTime;
        // if(downloadTimeTemp==0) downloadTimeTemp=1;
        // from mil to sec
        // TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(downloadTime)
        long bytespersecond = (long) (bytesIn / downloadTimeTemp) * 1000;
        double kilobits = bytespersecond * Constants.BYTE_TO_KILOBIT;
        double kilobytes = bytespersecond * Constants.BYTE_TO_KILOBYTE;// Constants.BYTE_TO_KILOBIT;
        //double megabits = kilobits * Constants.KILOBIT_TO_MEGABIT;

        double megabits = bytespersecond*0.000000953674;
        info.setDownspeed(bytespersecond);
        info.setKilobits(kilobits);
        info.setMegabits(megabits);

        TotalKB += kilobits;
        TotalTime += downloadTime;
        Utility.debugMessage(" downloadTest time in Downloading buffer",
                "bytespersecond = " + bytespersecond);
        Utility.debugMessage(" downloadTest time in Downloading buffer",
                "kilobits = " + kilobits);
        Utility.debugMessage(" Total downloadTest time in Downloading buffer TotalKB = "
                + TotalKB + " , TotalTime = " + TotalTime);
        return info;
    }

    public static  final double EDGE_THRESHOLD = 176.0;
    public static  final double BYTE_TO_KILOBIT = 0.0078125;
    public static  final double KILOBIT_TO_MEGABIT = 0.0009765625;
    public static final double BYTE_TO_KILOBYTE=0.000976562;
```

please let me know if some thing is wrong:

300Mbps WIFI router i am getting`enter code here`
75Mbps upload and
500 to 750 Mbps download speed

I am running the server on my machine and accessing it via a 300Mbps router over the LAN?